# C++ gettext doesn't translate (Windows 8.1)

Tags: c++, windows, gettext

I tried almost all solutions I found on web/stackoverflow.

Here is my shortened code:

```
#include "gettext.h"

std::string locale(setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));
MessageBoxA(NULL, locale.c_str(), "Locale", MB_OK); // prints out 'German_Germany.1252'
std::string lclocale = "LC_ALL=" + locale";

if(0 == putenv(lclocale.c_str()))
    MessageboxA(NULL, "Set locale seccussful", "Locale", MB_OK);
else
    MessageboxA(NULL, "Set locale error", "Locale", MB_OK);

std::string domain("xyz_locale");
textdomain(domain.c_str());
bindtextdomain(domain.c_str(), "./xyz_locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset(domain.c_str(), "UTF-8"); // same problem without this line
```

What I already tried:

- Set locale (LC_ALL) manually to

  - de
  - german
  - de_DE
  - German_Germany.1252

Here is my directory structure for locale:

```
pathToDomain
    /(locale) //tried all names mentioned above
        /LC_MESSAGES
            /(domain).mo
```

I already tried to set path absolute ("C:/....../(domain)")

Translation(-files) are made with PoEdit. *.po files are encodet with UTF-8, line endings are set to windows (setting in PoEdit).

I've downloaded gettext stuff from here:

- [ftp.gnome.org](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/)
- [mlocati.github.io](http://mlocati.github.io/gettext-iconv-windows/)

but there is no difference in result with them.

I copied `gettext.h` from `gettext-tools-dev_0.18.1.1-2.win32/share/gettext` to `/include` directory of my project.

Edit:

I already read through [gettext windows FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/FAQ.html#windows_woe32)

Comment: I have same problem in a simple C hello world application (based in [this article](https://mohan43u.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/gnu-gettext-yet-another-tutorial/)) and I've tried all steps above, however it doesn't work here too. Any string is translated, no logs, no errors, no problem compiling/linking. I still trying to solve it.